# How to use DSL plugin to download source code from VSTS

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am maintaining my source code in VSTS (Version Control is GIT). For CI process I am using Jenkins.

I would like create a dynamic job using **DSL** plugin and that dynamic job should download the code from VSTS.

So how can I pass credentials to download code from VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like credentials binding plugin for build jobs
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: I think it would be good if we use credential object instead of binding plugin. Becuase I am created dynamic job using DSL, so I think if we can provide credential object it can map in new job easily. if we want to download code from github use can pass credential object ID, but my issue with VSTS

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the same process you configured with Github. The only difference is that for VSTS, you have to create a Personal Access Token or enable Alternate Credential and use that as the credentials in Jenkins.

```
scm {
    git
    {
    remote {
        name('origin')
        url('https://vstsaccount.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/Reponame')
        credentials('vstspat')
    }
}
```